# How do I set and save to a Rails API a Backbone collection nested within a Backbone Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, has-many

I want to nest a Backbone collection (Profiles) within a Backbone Model (Guild), and populate this collection with one Profile model (to start with).

My goal is that when a user creates a new Guild, the model corresponding to this user should be added to the "users" attribute of the Guild.

Therefore in my View I call a createGuild function that is defined within my model, which takes as an argument the model for the Profile of the logged in user.

```
createGuild(
    attrs: CreatableGuildArgs,
    profile: Backbone.Model,
    error: (errors: string[]) => void,
    success: () => void
  ) {

    this.set(attrs);
    this.set('users', new Profiles());
    this.get("users").add(profile);

    console.log(this.get("users").length);
    console.log(this.get("users").at(0));

    this.save(
      {},
      {
        url: this.urlRoot(),

        success: () => success(),
        error: (_, jqxhr) => {
          error(this.mapServerErrors(jqxhr?.responseJSON));
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

The two console.logs work fine within my createGuild function: I see a Profiles collection populated with one user profile, of length 1.

However, the call to the save function is not working and returns the following error in my terminal :

```
Started POST "/guilds" for 172.18.0.1 at 2020-11-23 19:05:56 +0000
Cannot render console from 172.18.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
 Processing by GuildsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"name"=>"gsdfgdhtfg", "ang"=>"GDG", "users"=>"[object Object]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2121)

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "[object Object]":String):
  
app/controllers/guilds_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

In my chrome console I get : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Here are my Rails models :

```
class Guild < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :img
    has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

    validates :img, blob: { content_type: :image }
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 20}
    validates :ang, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 5}
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :avatar
    belongs_to :guild, optional: true

    validates :avatar, blob: { content_type: :image, size_range: 1..5.megabytes }
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :name, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 32}
    validates :login, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

And the Rails controller for the create method of guild:

```
  def create
    @guild = Guild.create(guild_params)
    if @guild.save
        @guild
    else
        render json: @guild.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def guild_params
    params.permit(:name, :ang, :img, :users)
  end
```

And here is my json.jbuilder files :

- _guild.json.jbuilder :

```
json.extract! guild, :id, :name, :ang, :points, :atWar, :created_at, :updated_at
json.img_url url_for(guild.img) if guild.img.attached?
json.users guild.users do |json, user|
  json.partial! user
end
```

- create.json.jbuilder :

```
json.partial! "guilds/guild", guild: @guild
```

And finally, here is my complete Guild model :

```
export default class Guild extends Backbone.Model {

  constructor(options?: any) {
    super(options);
  }

  urlRoot = () => "http://localhost:3000/guilds";

  sync(method: string, model: Guild, options: JQueryAjaxSettings): any {
    if (method == "create") {
      var formData = new FormData();

      _.each(model.attributes, function (value, key) {
        formData.append(key, value);

      });
      _.defaults(options || (options = {}), {
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
      });
    }
    return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
  }

  createGuild(
    attrs: CreatableGuildArgs,
    profile: Backbone.Model,
    error: (errors: string[]) => void,
    success: () => void
  ) {

    this.set(attrs);

    this.set('users', new Profiles());
    this.get("users").add(profile);

    console.log(this.get("users").length);
    console.log(this.get("users").at(0));

    this.save(
      {},
      {
        url: this.urlRoot(),

        success: () => success(),
        error: (_, jqxhr) => {
          error(this.mapServerErrors(jqxhr?.responseJSON));
        },
      }
    );
  }

  mapServerErrors(errors: Record<string, string[]>) {
    return Object.keys(errors).map((key) => `${key} ${errors[key].join(",")}`);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you